# Ajax request has invalid characters

Tags: jquery, ajax

I created an AJAX request. In the new browsers it works fine, but IE7 tells me there is an error with characters in the line, where  `function: 'gettestvaraibles'` stands. Can someone tell me where the error could be?

```
$.ajax('http://testurl/?eID=testid', {
    data: {
        function: 'gettestvaraibles',
        game_id: '630',
        game_score: '50'
    },
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        alert(errorThrown.message);
    },
    success: function() {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Function is a reserved keyword. You need to either change it, or wrap it in quotes:

```
data: {
    "function": 'gettestvaraibles',
    "game_id": '630',
    "game_score": '50'
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put quotes around `function`, because it's a keyword in JavaScript:

```
data: {
       'function': 'gettestvaraibles',
       'game_id': '630',
       'game_score': '50'
}
```