# JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to access a ASP.NET handler from Ajax. I am passing data to it using an anchor tag and returning some *test* string. Following is the code:

**Ajax Code**

```
function incvote(topicid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WCAccess.ashx",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "desid": "topicid" }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            return response.d;
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

            alertify.error("Some error occured. Please try again.");
        },
        //async: true
    });
```

**Handler Code**

```
public class WCAccess : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string jsonString = string.Empty;
        List<ArgsVals> argsList = new List<ArgsVals>();
        context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        using (var inputStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
        {
            jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
        }

        argsList = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ArgsVals>>(jsonString);
        string resp = "";
        foreach (ArgsVals arg in argsList)
        {
            resp += arg.desid;
        }
        context.Response.Write("<text>"+resp+"</text>");
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public class ArgsVals
    {
        public string desid { get; set; }
        //public int vtype { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Everything is working well until the control leaves `context.Response.Write()` statement. The data `resp` is getting the data nicely. But the problem is, Javascript is showing this error: `JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character`.

I searched SO and other websites. And I also tried this solution: [Ajax request has invalid characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119453/ajax-request-has-invalid-characters)
But nothing seem to work. Same error persists.

Comment: data: JSON.stringify({ desid: topicid }),

Comment: Already tried all quoted and non-quoted variations. Nothing worked.

Comment: alertify.error() what does this do ?

Comment: try to add to the handler code Response.End() after context.Response.Write("<text>"+resp+"</text>").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to return HTML/XML instead of JSON in your response.

```
context.Response.Write("<text>"+resp+"</text>");
```

Read the [JSON webpages](http://www.json.org/) for the structure of the message you are meant to send back.

Comment: Thanks this was what actually happening. I changed the data-type to `html` and it worked. **One more thing I want to ask** is that how can I change the anchor tag's text with this response from handler? I am doing it like this: ` document.getElementById("suplink").innerHTML=response.d;` but its changing the text to `undefined` instead of  `test` as passed by handler. Please help.

Comment: You're using jQuery already so look at the addClass and removeClass functions and add some CSS for color. Also you should be using something like $('#suplink').html( response);

Comment: Ok now I got it. And a problem after converting data-type to html is that I am unable to deserialize and store data in `argsList` at server side. Its showing 0 elements. But the json string in getting the data.